# Inserting data into an arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

My question is specific to Java. I have a Get and Set method that will get and set the data.
I would like to add this into an arraylist. How can I do this ?

Below I've shown a small sample of what I've done so far.

```
public class GetSetMethod {

    String newcompanyid = null;

    public String getNewcompanyid() {
        return newcompanyid;
    }

    public void setNewcompanyid(String newcompanyid) {
        this.newcompanyid = newcompanyid;
    }
}
```

In my MainActivity I am using this object

```
    public class MainActivity{
       ArrayList<String> bulk = new ArrayList<String>();

       GetSetMethod  objSample = new GetSetMethod();

       objSample.setNewcompanyid(newcompanyid);
    }
```

How can I put the values of objSample into the array list. I've tried using

```
bulk.add(newcompanyid);
```

But since I've a large amount of data to be passed (and there is a for loop also), it calls the function many times.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: So, what's wrong? If you have a lot of data you have to call `add()` many times. What's the question?

Comment: what's the problem with using the add-method often? if you have a Collection of data, you can use addAll, but it won't increase the performance very much

Comment: *it calls the function many times.* -- The fact that the `add`-method is called many times seems to make quite a lot of sense if you have large amount of data, no?

Comment: Well AlexR I am making an android application that will insert the value into the database. Opening the database and closing it every time wouldn't be proper. My goal is to open it once insert all the values and then close. My previous approach of opening and closing continuously has some serious drawbacks.

Comment: OK, this is absolutely different question. I'd recommend you to ask it clearly with code snippets and some descriptions of your use case. I am sure you will get better recommendations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<GetSetMethod> list = new ArrayList<GetSetMethod>();
GetSetMethod objSample = new GetSetMethod();
objSample.setNewcompanyid("Any string you want");
list.add(objSample);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think there is no other way than adding each element to the list. Just a few tips:

```
ArrayList<String> bulk = new ArrayList<String>();
```

you should replace the code above with:

```
List<String> bulk = new ArrayList<String>();
```

that allows you to switch between different List implementations(ArrayList, LinkedList, ...).

If the data to be added are already into another collection you can do the following instead of adding each element:

```
List<Integer> a;
List<Integer> b;

....

b.addAll(a);
```

In addition, if you need to initialize a List with a set of elements known at compile time, you can do the following:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way around it, if you want to add "large amount" of data to a List you will have a "large amount" of add() calls in your code.